# Regex to match this kind of method signature

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have this kind of method signature I want to parse:

```
.method [list of words than can or cant appear] MethodName([List of params])ReturnType
```

as an example here 2 methods signatures I need to parse:

```
.method Paracasa(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
.method public static OnDone()V
```

The main problem is that the words appearing between .method and MethodName can exist or not and I need to capture them if they exist. I have a solution for this, but I'm sure there will be a cleaner solution that I would like to know. My solution is

```
\.method(?:\s+(.*)\s+|\s+)(.+)\((.*)\)\s*(.*)
```

As you can see I have added the two options, I mean, if this group of words between .method and Methodname appears or it don't. But seems dirty to me.

Could it be done another way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We're talking about java method names here, so you want to match keywords like public, private, protected, static etc.?

Comment: Well, no. You are right this comes from a java source, but this is smali and in the [list of words than can or cant appear] I have seen things that do not match with a java keyword (can't rember now). So this is why I want to capture all the text in this part to be safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\.method\s+(.*?)\s*(\w+)\((.*)\)(\w+)
```

very similar to your regex.

```
\.method\s+
(.*?)  # non-greedy match, matches only extra keywords like public etc.
\s*    # so the previous non-greedy match won't match trailing space
(\w+)  # I suppose method names can only be alphanumeric or underscore
\((.*)\)  # May cause problems if list of params include another parentheses - is no longer "regular" language
(\w+)  # Same as with method name, only alphanumeric or underscore?
```

My biggest concern is with parentheses in parameter list, as it will make this problem unfit for regular expressions (although probably possible with some extensions).

Also, if you want to be more strict with parsing of method name and return type, you can use `([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*)` instead on `(\w+)`. This is common regular expression for identifier names in most languages, as far as i know.

Comment: why you say "My biggest concern is with parentheses in parameter list, as it will make this problem unfit for regular expressions"? Do you mean, capture an unkown number of params?

Comment: @Notbad I didn't realize it's method declaration (not method call), so another parentheses in parameter list is probably not valid. What i meant was another parentheses inside parentheses, which would cause trouble with both my and yours regex.